# how to resolve git error while pushing to the remote repo

Tags: git, github, error-handling, pull-request, git-push

While trying to push my code to git-repo, I am getting the following error as shown in the figure.

A couple of days ago, I created the different branches and pull requests as part of my test, but later I removed the branches and only have the main branch left. I then pull the main branch to my local repo (after committing changes to my local main branch), and then tried to push and then get the following error.

How can I override this error?
PS. I am the sole developer of the code and do not need anyone to review it.

[image: Error while Pushing to remote repo]

Comment: Could you paste the command/output as text into the question?

Answer (score 1):

In the repository's Settings tab in GitHub, under Branches, it sounds like you have a Branch protection rule.

[image: GitHub Branch protection rule settings]